# How to prevent rails mailer to open new gmail login session each time it sends an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a task scheduled to send thousands of reporting emails to different users of my app. I configured Gmail to send the emails. However, after a few hundred of emails sent, I get the following error:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts,
>   please try again later.

As mentioned [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/543007/google-smtp-error-454-4-7-0-too-many-login-attempts-please-try-again-later), I set up a DNS record but it still doesn't work.

How can I change the configuration of the rails mailer in order to only open once the Gmail session in order to be able to send thousands emails in a row?

My task:

```
  task :send_weekly_stats => :environment do
    User.each do |u|
      UserMailer.weekly_report_email(u.id).deliver_now
    end
  end
```

My mailer action:

```
def weekly_report_email(user_id)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  @email = @user.email
  @subject = 'Weekly Report'
  mail(to: @email, subject: @subject)
end
```

Comment: Anecdote: Gmail and the likes aren't really meant for such use. Is there any reason why you're not using a service like Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc?

Comment: The link you have attached, there is a good sample written in Ruby by Luis, check that one. Make one time authenticate and keep the session for all emails.

Comment: So, I do it outside of the rails mailer?